# lookahead using (?=$) to match desired result

Tags: python

Suppose such a string

```
In [12]: s = "spy.abpy[.py.py.py"
```

I want to match the last py using regex,

I am aware that `$` indicate the end of a string, so I use lookahead to look the head of `$` for py

```
In [22]:  re.search(r"py(?=$)", s)                                                                                
Out[22]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 18), match='py'>
In [27]: s[16:18]                                                                                                 
Out[27]: 'py'
```

I am excited about the result, because I just initially play around.

How could it happen? Is there official documents to explain.

There not exists a `$` in the string?

Comment: You don't need to use lookahead for this, just use `r"py$"`, this will achieve the samething, basically, `$` matches the end of line, if you want to search for `$` in the string, you'll have to escape it in regex: `'\$'`

Comment: You say `I'm aware that $ indicates the end of a string`, so the lookahead is looking for the end of the string. You've pretty much answered your own question